# What is the difference between operator++(); call and ++(*this)?

Tags: c++

I'm calling operator++() in my class constructor, and it is recommended to use operator++(); instead of ++(*this). What is the difference between the two?

Comment: There isn't any.

Comment: "it is recommended" - by whom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is essentially no difference. `++(*this)` is rewritten to an invocation of `operator++()`.

It is possible that in obscure cases the overload resolution could be different, but you probably want to avoid the scenarios where that would be the case anyway.

I would use `++(*this)`.